# Do Vedas teach Yogasana? If so, what are the good sources to learn it?

Tags: vedas, yoga

As the question states, do Vedas teach Yogasana? If so, what are the good sources to learn the asanas?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/508/2995) to [Is Yoga a part of Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/505/2995) and [this sacred-texts.com link](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/yoga/index.htm) for resources.

Comment: Asanas are merely gymnastic exercises. A few of them can help one in the beginning to help strengthen the body for sitting in mediation, but so can other exercises. Doing them too much or often will lead one to think more about the body rather than the spirit.