# Have any Hindu astrologers correctly predicted that Joe Biden would become the next US president?

Tags: astrology

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/Avadhutwaghbjp/status/1321801126321156098) shows an astrological chart prepared by an Indian/Hindu astrologer predicting Donald Trump would be elected to office a second time.

> Shree **Donald Trump shall retain the office of President of America IInd time**. He wins by 4 lakh votes minimum and 9 lakh maximum but **Trump shall be blamed for managing and hacking the votes**.
>
> [image]

Another astrologer (Acharya Salil Kumar) in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/M4D8Mr_5kdg?t=309) also predicted in February 2020 that Trump would beat any Democratic candidate by a good margin. In a [video from June](https://youtu.be/QkjkMdZv-B8?t=328) he reiterates the same:

> Trump vs Biden, who will be next US President | Astrological Calculations by Acharya Salil
>
> Jun 27, 2020
>
> No matter what the circumstances are in USA or the world, **the next President of the United States of America will be Mr. Donald Trump. He will definitely win.**

Since Joe Biden is scheduled to be inaugurated on January 20, 2021, as the next US president, both these astrologers have failed badly at predicting the outcome of the 2020 US election.

**But have any Indian/Hindu astrologers succeeded in predicting the result correctly?**

Also, does Hindu astrology allow for such predictions in the first place?

Proponents of astrology argue that it is an exact science so how do they explain these failed predictions? Is the problem always with details concerning the subject's (native's) date/time of birth?

Comment: Since the odds of correctly predicting the election outcome stood at a very favourable 1 to 1 the answer to your first question is very likely to be yes. As far as explaining failed predictions is concerned  the [No true Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) fallacy or some variant thereof could be resorted to

Comment: What does it have to do with Hinduism?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't astrology and the part that deals with predictions related to it part of Hinduism? There is even a tag for the topic on this site. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sv. Sounds like a political question though.

Comment: I think it's best to stick to the objective questions in my post without attributing motives since according to [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/we-are-neither-hindus-nor-indians), this site is about Hinduism. This is not a Hindu website. So criticism of ideas within Hinduism is fair. ("...we must appreciate questions that have been written with a critical point of view....If you are more inclined to resent rather than rejoice the differences between us, then this may not be the site for you.") @Ikshvaku

Comment: "Does Hindu astrology allow for such predictions in the first place?" - How is this political? "How do they explain these failed predictions? Is the problem always with details concerning the subject's (native's) date/time of birth?" - How are these political?

Comment: It is political because you're asking about Hindu astrological predictions for *Joe Biden*. You could've just asked, "how does Hinduism explain failed predictions?", or "why do astrological predictions fail sometimes?"

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the same person who was adamant in closing this question on [new age gurus and yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/is-there-a-dilution-in-yoga-by-new-age-gurus) will ask the above question.

Comment: There are two sincere questions (bold face): 1. `But have any Indian/Hindu astrologers succeeded in predicting the result correctly?` There would be surely someone who did so, it might or might not be according to the required effort as asked in **`does Hindu astrology allow for such predictions in the first place?`** 2. **`Proponents of astrology argue that it is an exact science so how do they explain these failed predictions?`** Looks on topic to me. It isn't political because there could have been other examples as well. It isn't asking about any political process, political activism, etc.

Comment: The fact is this, better than prediction we can reson why a certain thing happened. Although predictions are part of market needs, the astrological reasons of why a certain thing happens is more straightforward to come with. Since prediction also depend on astrologers chart itself, the time he predicts it, and how the time will be for him during the results of predictions!!

Comment: @sv. May be you can change the title to that i.e. "Does Hindu astrology allow for such predictions in the first place?" read what ikshvaku suggested in one of his comments. Currently your question looks political based question and hence closed.

Comment: Read the beautiful explanation provided by Severus Snape, I can't explain you any clearer than that. The question is not about Joe Biden. It's about astrological predictions. The topic of prediction could be elections, someone's career, future of a child, natural calamities, stock markets, etc. @TheLittleNaruto

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**

for the question *Have any Hindu astrologers correctly predicted that Joe Biden would become the next US president?*

[PVR Narasimharao](https://www.vedicastrologer.org/personal.htm), predicted about Joe Biden winning in 2020 US presidential elections. It can be observed in [this](https://youtu.be/76T9RjFXr5w?t=3214) and [this](https://youtu.be/lKpPaKIvN5c?t=941) video.

Comment: The YouTube video doesn't count considering that the prediction was made in 2017 where he was talking about his possible impeachment. My question is specifically about 2020 US Presidential Elections. The third link is a huge PDF and has only a single line that says "Impeachment of Sri Donald Trump". BTW, considering that Trump wasn't impeached, should we consider it as Mulugu's failed prediction?

Comment: Can you point me to the place in the PDF where he's specifically talking about 2020 US Presidential Elections?

Comment: 'Trump will loose his position' - meaning he'll be impeached even before the 2020 Elections, but that didn't happen...my question was specifically about 2020 Elections. He's saying things like "Trump needs psychiatric treatment" in the video so I don't take his predictions seriously. They are not even about 2020 Elections - if they were any they should be in the PDF.

Comment: @sv. I revised the answer and it is in English now.

Comment: @SeverusSnape Thanks :)

Comment: @hanugm Nice answer. I never understood how the above astrologer gave a prediction without even looking at D10, arudha padas or anything. Forget being wrong, It's not even a prediction!

Comment: Since you answered my title question, I'm going to upvote your answer but just wanted to make sure you already voted to reopen my question. Also, if you can quote in words the summary of the election prediction from the second video that would be great.